# Animation rendering each frame twice

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, animation

I have an issue that happens sometimes. When rendering an image sequence animation, each frame is rendered twice. The second one above the first. It doubles the render time. I have cheked off the compositing and the sequencer. Tried turning off the combined pass and cheking "render single layer". By the way, I have tried every 2.8 versions and using cycles.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Didn't you enable the "Stereoscopy" in the Output Properties?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not using it.

Comment: I am having the same problem (more than twice, consistently) and posted a new question at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214931/each-frame-rendering-several-times-extending-render-job

Answer (score 2):

I may have an explanation. I was doing some motion tracking, and when I rendered each frame was rendering twice in two identical "layers". This doubled render time, as you explained.

The thing that fixed it was going into Layer Properties in the Properties panel on the right. Then go into `View Layer` and check `Render Single Layer`. This solved the problem for me.

I hope this helps!

[image: How to render only a single layer.]

Comment: My god thanks for this!  I had this problem before and totally forgot what the solution was.  Your answer was a Eureka! moment.  Cheers