# each frame rendering several times, extending render job

Tags: rendering

I have a file (attached) that renders each frame several times.  In Eevee it is about thrice, and in Cycles about five times per frame as you can see in this

[image]

[youtube video capture](https://youtu.be/NyvzfY1d444).  The [blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bebaxwkb7k5no8e/renderThis.blend?dl=0) is a reduced  file with fast and low quality renders to demonstrate the problem.  This appears to be slowing my complete rendering (with a walkthrough camera) to a near screeching halt.

I can even see the rendering repeating in a console output from a render cmd like:

> blender -b "renderProblem.blend" -s 1 -e 1 -a

I have never experienced a render that seems to redraw from the start as it completes a frame.  Explanations are willkommen!

Comment: You have multiple layers. Go to the layer properties and disable the "Use for rendering " on layers you don't want to render

Comment: Wow: it very much did. thanks!  if you want to copy/paste into answer below, I can accept it and you get credit.